# Is there any more convenient way to add Ignore Tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, ignored-tags

I wonder if there is a possibility to see all tags in a long list so it will be easier to chose which ones could be chosen to be ignored?

Currently I have tons of tags in Ignore list but there are always more of them and I'm even do not aware of their existence before I actually see them for the first time.

Comment: Possibly moving the text box to the top of the tag cloud that it applies to would be more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore a tag simply by hovering over the tag and clicking the star to toggle from favourite, ignored, and normal.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the asterisk to ignore a group of tags; for example, if you use *drupal-**, you would ignore any tags starting with *drupal-*, such as [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views), and [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this more quickly is to use wildcards in your ignore list.  A `*` matches zero or more characters.

For example, I'm not a Flash developer, and I'm uninterested in Flash questions.  I have `flash*` in my ignored tag lists, which ignores [flash](/questions/tagged/flash), [flash-builder](/questions/tagged/flash-builder), [flash-cs5](/questions/tagged/flash-cs5), [flash-cs4](/questions/tagged/flash-cs4), [flash-player](/questions/tagged/flash-player), etc.  This speeds up the process significantly.

I usually leave off the hyphen when using the asterisk, some tags mush the words together without a hyphen and then you don't have to ignore both `flash` and `flash-*`.

Also, remember that you can add tags to your ignore list from the Questions page.  If you see a question that you don't want to see, just scroll to the insertion box and add the tag.  It will display any tags that you might want to capture with `*`:

[image: Like Windows. Heh.]

Adding tags from the questions page dilutes the time requirement, making it feel less onerous.  Don't feel like you need to fill your list with everything you want to ignore all at once, it's plenty easy to fill over time.